# how to get the direct parent in sass interpolation of &

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to use {$} to get the most direct parent?
In the example below '&#{&}' is not working as I expected, I managed to work around it using mixin.

```
@mixin modifier($modifier, $block: &) {
    &#{"."+$block}--#{$modifier} {
        @content;
    }
}
.namespace{
  $button : 'btn';
  .#{$button} {
    line-height: 1;
    @include modifier('big', $button){ // working but not clean
       padding-top: 8px;
    }
    &#{&}--big{ // not working as {&} is interpolated to namespace .btn
       padding-top: 12px;
    }
  }
}
```

Compiled to:

```
.namespace .btn {
  line-height: 1;
}
.namespace .btn.btn--big {
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.namespace .btn.namespace .btn--big {
  padding-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Do you expect compile `.namespace .btn--big` ?

Comment: No, I expected `namespace .btn.btn--big`

Answer (score 0):

The construct looks a bit odd to me – but you could do it like:

```
.namespace  {
    $class: ".btn";
    #{$class} { line-height: 1; }
    #{$class}#{$class}--big { padding-top: 8px; }
    & #{$class}#{&} #{$class}--big { padding-top: 12px; }
}
```

...or using selector append

```
.namespace .btn {
  line-height: 1;
  @at-root { 
    #{selector-append(&,".btn")}--big{ padding-top: 8px; }
    #{selector-append(&,&)}--big{ padding-top: 12px; }
  }
}
```

both compiling to:

```
.namespace .btn { line-height: 1; }
.namespace .btn.btn--big { padding-top: 8px; }
.namespace .btn.namespace .btn--big { padding-top: 12px; }
```

Comment: The expected result was, so this won't work
`namespace .btn.btn--big`

Comment: Not sure I get your question then – the above produces exactly the output described. Can you update your question with the output you want